# regular expression replace to quickly escape variables

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, replace

I'm trying create a regular expression to wrap an escape around all the variables in my view when I do a find and replace.

Current code

```
echo $this->cust['id'];
echo $this->cust['firstname'];
echo $this->cust['lastname'];
echo $this->cust['postCode'];
```

should become

```
echo $this->escape($this->cust['id']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['firstname']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['lastname']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['postCode']);
```

$this->cust is not consistent as it may be $this->quote or $this->order in different views

Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Comment: So, the match would be anything that begins with `$this->`, is that correct? Are you trying to write a script that will modify your code?

Comment: Yeah, also want to replace ]; with ]); a the end of each line

Comment: I think this would be pretty easy using Structural Search in the PhpStorm IDE, do you use it by any chance?

Comment: My question is, are you looking to run a PHP script on your `current.php` file that produces an `new_current.php` file with the replacements in there?

Comment: Yeah, i am using PHPstorm

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure PHP solution to this then you can use `preg_replace`

/tmp/current.php

```
echo "some other code";
echo $this->cust['id'];
echo $this->cust['firstname'];
echo $this->cust['lastname'];
echo $this->cust['postCode'];
echo $this->order['size'];
function x() { echo $this->anything['derp']; }
```

/tmp/regex.php

```
<?php
$ifile = '/tmp/current.php';
$ofile = '/tmp/new_current.php';

$ifh = fopen($ifile, "r");
$ofh = fopen($ofile, "w");

$regex = '#(\$this->[^]]+])#';
$replace = '$this->escape($1)';

while(($line = fgets($ifh)) !== false) {
    if($new_line = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $line)) {
        fwrite($ofh, $new_line);
    }
    else fwrite($ofh, $line);
}
?>
```

Run: /tmp/regex.php, yeilds:

```
echo "some other code";
echo $this->escape($this->cust['id']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['firstname']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['lastname']);
echo $this->escape($this->cust['postCode']);
echo $this->escape($this->order['size']);
function x() { echo $this->escape($this->anything['derp']); }
```